# The input document is not a stylesheet (the XSL namespace is not declared in the root element)

Tags: java, xml, xslt, wildfly-10

I'm getting the following error in jboss/wildfly 10,

```
ERROR:  'The input document is not a stylesheet (the XSL namespace is not declared in the root element).'
FATAL ERROR:  'Could not compile stylesheet'
javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Could not compile stylesheet
    at org.apache.xalan.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:832)
    at org.apache.xalan.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTransformer(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:618)
```

My XSL is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="no" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <!-- html content here -->

    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/st/*">
    <!-- html content here -->
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/mv/*">
    <!-- html content here -->
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Could you help to resolve this error?

Comment: how do you pass the stylesheet to the TransformerFactory?

Comment: Source  xslSource = new StreamSource(fullPathxslName); Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(xslSource);

Comment: your xsl is fine. Are you sure that `fullPathxslName` points to the right file?

Comment: yes, i verified and it points to right file. i'm running this in jboss/wildfly 10, any issue in jboss?

Comment: any pointer for this issue?

Comment: If you want an answer you are going to have to show us the Java code that compiles the stylesheet.  The problem is not in the XSL, so it must be in the Java code.  Maybe you are not passing the correct file or buffer to the compiler.  Have you verified that the Java is correct?